# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 8 (Enterprise Evaluation)

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2008-r2

When I Try to install **SQL Server 2008 R2** on **Windows 8** (Enterprise Evaluation), a compatibility warning massage is displayed,

[image]

Tried `Get help online` option but it is says `No solution found`, but setup starts when I select `Run the program without getting help`.

Do I have to install any Service Pack or Update to make it compatible or SQL Server 2008/R2 is not supported on this version of windows? and what are the effects if I run the setup ignoring the warning message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Install SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 8 Beta (en-US)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7899.install-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-server-8-beta-en-us.aspx#Installing_SQL_Server_2008R2) on TechNet, you can just click on *Run the program without getting help* and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

it looks like you need to install the SP1 of Sql Server 2008 R2, here are where to download from Microsoft site: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506123341/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727).

Select your language and your version (32/64-bit) then, you install first the Management Studio from SQL and then the service pack.

Here is the blog where I found the solution: ["Installing SQL Server on Windows 8"](https://web.archive.org/web/20151205144416/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/01/installing-sql-server-on-windows-8.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I solved it. You need .NET framework 3.5(include 2.0 and 3.0) to install the sql server.

So, first you must install or download .NET framework 3.5 in your system